# Execute shell command with nodejs

Tags: node.js

I got this code snippet

```
function run_cmd(cmd, args, cb ) {
  console.log('[run_cmd] cmd = ' + cmd);
  var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
  var child = spawn(cmd, args);
  var resp = '';
  child.stderr.on('data', function(data) { console.log('err = ' + data) });
  child.stdout.on('data', function (buffer) { resp += buffer.toString() });
  child.stdout.on('close', function(code) {
    console.log('[run_cmd] exit code = ' + code + ', resp = ' + resp);
    cb (resp);
  });
}
```

which works fine when i execute simple command like `ls`.

```
run_cmd( "ls", ["-l"], function(text) { console.log (text) });
```

But it doesn't get execute when i tried to exec this command

```
 libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf /home/username/input_file.rtf --outdir ~/tmp
```

by this

```
run_cmd( "libreoffice", ["--headless", "--convert-to pdf", file_path, "--outdir ~/tmp"], function(text) { console.log (text) });
```

I got exit code = `false`, blank as response. How would i debug this?

The command is not executed (output file not created).

The command works just fine when I manually paste in the terminal.

Comment: You should listen for the stderr if error occurs.

Comment: @VuDang So i added ` child.stderr.on('data', function(data) { console.log('err = ' + data) });` and still nothing. No error whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is caused by a tilde in the path (see [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/2857)). Could you try to expand the tilde by hand and re-run the function?

Comment: I just figured it out as well. Came back here and saw your answer. (+1 and accepted).

Comment: is there a node.js function to expand shell variables or tilda ?